# Ruby on Rails model association issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, model-associations

Sorry for the vague title, but it's a little much to explain in a sentence.

I've got three models, User, Device, and DeviceMessage. Their relationships are fairly simple:

- a User `has_many :devices`,
- a Device `belongs_to :user`,
- a Device `has_many :device_messages`,
- and a DeviceMessage `belongs_to :device`.

Rails provides ways to start playing with these associations quickly, like the ability to get all device messages that belong to a certain user (from any device).

In order to do this, I defined a method in the User model:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      ...
      has_many :devices, :as => : owner #Other entities may "own" a device

      def device_feed
        DeviceMessage.that_belong_to_user(self)
      end
    end
```

And I define the called method in the DeviceMessage model:

```
    class DeviceMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
      ...
      belongs_to :device

      def self.that_belong_to_user(user)
        device_ids = "SELECT owner_id FROM devices WHERE owner_id = :user_id 
                     AND owner_type = \"User\""
        where("device_id IN (#{device_ids})", user_id: user.id)
      end
    end
```

I define a user page where they can associate a device to their account (the device has a name as well), and upon adding the device to the account, it will add the name to a list of device names in a pane to the left, while showing the user's device feed much like a twitter feed (yes, I followed Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial). At this point it is important to note that I am using helper functions to keep track of the current user so I can display this information when a user visits the root_path while logged in. When visiting the root_path, the controller for the root_path is defined so that:

```
    if user_signed_in?
      @device_feed_items = current_user.device_feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
```

And this all works perfectly!

So... what's the issue? When I create a new user via the signup page, and associate the device via the device-association page, I am redirected to the root_path, the device name **is** correctly displayed in the left pane (which mean the device is correctly associated with the new user), but the device_feed **is not** displayed.

I've used the Rails console to verify that the device messages *should be* showing (`User.find(2).devices.first.device_messages.first` displays the first message associated with the first device that is newly associated with the 2nd user), so I know that I need to reach down into the database to get a fresh rather than cached copy of the current_user, but I'm confused because it seems like that should be happening every time the `user.device_feed` method is called because of it's use of `where()` which is a part of the query API...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any and all answers.

-MM

Answer (score 0):

I am just wondering why you have the device_feed function.  For your feed display could you not just a loop like this one, this is

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :in_new_message_order, :joins => :device_messages, :order => "created_at DESC"      

end
```

Added a joined scope

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :devices, :as => : owner #Other entities may "own" a device
  scope :in_sort_order, order("message_date DESC")

  def device_feed
    DeviceMessage.that_belong_to_user(self)
  end
end
```

Above I have added a scope to sort your messages

```
<% user.devices.in_new_message_order.each do |device| %>
    <% device.device_messages_in_sort_order.each do |message| %>
        <%= ....render out the message %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The device feed will display everything in chronological order (with the latest message at the top of the feed) whereas the method provided would simply print out the messages in chronological order __per device__, rather than all together.

Comment: Maybe an alternative would be to add a relationship directly from the User model to the DeviceMessage model? Like User `has_many :device_messages, through: :devices` or something...?

Comment: Just hacked about with the answer based on your comment, perhaps it helps